# angular 4 how to render dynamic content from object

Tags: javascript, angular

Is it possible to generate "dynamic" html content inside a component form an object, something like this:

```
let fields = [
        {
            'field': 'name',
            'type': 'text',
            'attrs': [
                {
                    'class': 'name some-class',
                    'fxFlex': '70px',
                    'some-attr': 'some value',
                    '[ngClass]': '{"fa-check-square": isOk(item._id)'
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            'field': 'age',
            'type': 'number',
            'attrs': [
                {
                    'class': 'age some-class',
                    'fxFlex': '70px',
                    '[ngClass]': '{"fa-check-square": isOk(item._id)'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

And in the html:

```
    <app-fields [items]="fields"></app-fields>
```

What generate:

```
<div class="name some-class" fxFlex="70px" [ngClass]="{'fa-check-square': isOk(item._id) some-attr="some value">
    <label for="inp_name">Name:</label>
    <input id="inp_name" type="text" formControlName="name">
</div>
<div class="age some-class" fxFlex="70px" [ngClass]="{'fa-check-square': isOk(item._id)>
    <label for="inp_age">Age:</label>
    <input id="inp_age" type="text" formControlName="age">
</div>
```

I'm good with ng-templates, the problem is, how to pass the reference of the functions, and how to add not predefined attributes to dom elements.

Maybe the object structure not the best, but it was not a goal.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But Stack Overflow isn't here to write code for you. Do you have code you'd like to share where you've attempted something?

Comment: I would like to get basic concepts, not solutions ;)

Comment: We don't really do "basic concepts" here on Stack Overflow. Search the internet for those. There's likely one or two tutorials on how to generate HTML from an object in Angular.

Comment: I did, but i do not found what looks like usable, most answer is, there is no way to do that for now, but of course I would be happy if you or someone can help me and to others, who need similar things. I start to feel that, we should attach the links what we found before we ask to prevent similar comments as yours. As I know "stakoverflow questions" is for questions, not for find the solution and share it ("stakoverflow documentation is for that").

Comment: We do expect people to do research before asking on SO, yes. See [ask], under "Search, and research". You are encouraged to answer your own questions on Stack Overflow (there's even a checkbox for it when you ask a question), but the question has to follow the same rules for being on-topic: [help/on-topic].

Comment: I'm encouraged to answer my questions belive me :) And if I found well usable solution for this question, I will share here too. Maybe some of the visitors will give some idea whats enough me to solve the problem.